# Thymeleaf using path variables to th:href

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-el

Here's my code, where I'm iterating through:

```
<tr th:each="category : ${categories}">
     <td th:text="${category.idCategory}"></td>
     <td th:text="${category.name}"></td>
     <td>
         <a th:href="@{'/category/edit/' + ${category.id}}">view</a>
     </td>
</tr>
```

The URL it points to is supposed to be `/category/edit/<id of the category>`, but it says it could not parse the expression:

> Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "category.id"
>   (category-list:21)

Comment: Are u sure that `id` is a property of a category object? Or is `idCategory` semantically different?

Comment: what different between idCategory and id?

Comment: Do you have the rest of the stack trace?

Answer (score 117):

The right way according to [Thymeleaf documention for adding parameters](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) is:

```
<a th:href="@{/category/edit/{id}(id=${category.idCategory})}">view</a>
```

Comment: That's a very underappreciated answer . To my opinion that's the best one.

Answer (score 62):

I think your problem was a typo:

```
<a th:href="@{'/category/edit/' + ${category.id}}">view</a>
```

You are using `category.id`, but in your code is **`idCategory`**, as Eddie already pointed out.

This would work for you:

```
<a th:href="@{'/category/edit/' + ${category.idCategory}}">view</a>
```

Answer (score 29):

A cleaner and easier way to do this

```
<a href="somepage.html" th:href="@{|/my/url/${variable}|}">A Link</a>
```

I found this solution in [Thymeleaf Documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions) on "4.8 Literal substitutions".

Comment: Very nice. I hope people see this answer - this is far nicer and more compact than the other approaches listed here, avoiding the need for '...' or duplicating the names with the the (...) link syntax

Answer (score 14):

Your code looks syntactically correct, but I think your property doesn't exist to create the URL.

I just tested it, and it works fine for me.

Try using `category.idCategory` instead of `category.id`, for example…

```
  <tr th:each="category : ${categories}">
    <td th:text="${category.idCategory}"></td>
    <td th:text="${category.name}"></td>
    <td>
      <a th:href="@{'/category/edit/' + ${category.idCategory}}">view</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to go through a list of objects, display them as rows in a table, with each row being a link. This worked for me. Hope it helps.

```
// CUSTOMER_LIST is a model attribute
<table>
    <th:block th:each="customer : ${CUSTOMER_LIST}">
        <tr>
            <td><a th:href="@{'/main?id=' + ${customer.id}}" th:text="${customer.fullName}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </th:block>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

**You can use like**

1. My table is bellow like..

   ```
   <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Details</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr th:each="user: ${staffList}">
           <td><a th:href="@{'/details-view/'+ ${user.userId}}">Details</a></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   ```
2. Here is my controller ..

   ```
   @GetMapping(value = "/details-view/{userId}")
   public String details(@PathVariable String userId) { 

       Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).info("userId-->" + userId);

    return "user-details";
   }
   ```

Comment: This thing worked for me in this case: <a th:href="${'http://localhost:8080/reset-password?otp='} + ${otp}">Click Here to reset your Password.</a>

Answer (score 4):

I think you can try this:

```
<a th:href="${'/category/edit/' + {category.id}}">view</a>
```

Or if you have "idCategory" this:

```
<a th:href="${'/category/edit/' + {category.idCategory}}">view</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

html:

```html
 <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<a th:href="@{'/category/'+ ${item.idCategory}}">View</i></a>
```

Controller: `@PathVariable String parentId`

Comment: <a th:href="${'/category/edit/' + {category.idCategory}}">view</a>

Answer (score 2):

"List" is an object getting from backend and using iterator to display in table

"minAmount" , "MaxAmount" is an object variable 
"mrr" is an just temporary var to get value and iterate mrr to get data.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tbody>
<tr th:each="mrr,iterStat : ${list}">
        <td th:text="${mrr.id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${mrr.minAmount}"></td>
        <td th:text="${mrr.maxAmount}"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this one is a very easy method if you are in list of model foreach (var item in Modal) loop

> `<th:href="/category/edit/@item.idCategory>View</a>"`

> or

`<th:href="/category/edit/@item.idCategory">View</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **${yourVariable}**
for exampe `<th:href="/category/edit/__${yourVariable}__">View</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use thymeleaf preprocessing :

```
<tr th:each="category : ${categories}">
    <td th:text="${category.idCategory}"></td>
    <td th:text="${category.name}"></td>
    <td>
        <a th:href="@{__${category.idCategory}__}">view</a>
    </td>
 </tr>
```